# How do you just see the bones inside a model?

Tags: rigging

How do you just see the bones inside a model?

Comment: Hey there, while it's a legit question, i believe you should be able to solve this with the basic "Hide" option for the model that you do not want to see, thus leaving you with only the bones/armature. It would increase the quality of the question if you explain what you tried and where you had a problem, a picture showing the situation might also help clear some possible misinterpretations. As the question seems too simple, header and content the same, it might not be taken serious or get's down-voted. Might be helpful to take quick [tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Use X-ray option if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Bone/Armature and then Object data properties > Viewport Display > Select In Front.

[image]